# magento - hide grid filter , but not disable it

Tags: magento, grid

I want to use a form for filtering a grid in magento!
also I want to hide the column filters in this grid, so I used :

```
'filter'=>false,
```

Now the form does not work neither, What should I do to just hide the column filters, not disable them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer :),
In the **__construct** method of your grid, you should add this code :

```
    $this->setFilterVisibility(false);
```

This will hide the whole filter row. Just what I want!